# How to plot Phasor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have been working on Data Compression through SDT algorithm. I have been given a task to compress the data having 20001 points and I successfully compressed it into 944 points. Now I want to plot phasors in MATLAB. How to do it?

I used `plot3` command but unfortunately could not get the desired result.

My code:

```
clear
clc
load('s.mat');
[N,~]=size(a(:,1));
b=[]
s=1; %storage point
a(s,6)=a(1,2); %vs, store the first phasor
a(s,5)=a(1,1); %ts
a(s,7)=a(1,3); %alphas
for n=3:1:N
    p=n-1;
    vp=a(p,2);
    tp=a(p,1);
    alphap=a(p,3);
    vn=a(n,2);
    tn=a(n,1);
    alphan=a(n,3);
    vs=a(s,6); %vs
    ts=a(s,5);%ts
    alphas=a(s,7);%alphas 
    for i=s+1:n-1 %Condtion for Vi and Current Points
        ti=a(i,1);
        alphai=a(i,3);
        vi=a(i,2)*(cos(alphai)+1i*sin(alphai));%Phasors (Vi)
        vcomp=((vn-vs)/(tn-ts))*(ti-ts)+vs;
        alphacomp=((alphan-alphas)/(tn-ts))*(ti-ts)+alphas;
        vcpx=vcomp*(cos(alphacomp)+1i*sin(alphacomp));%Phasors (Vcomp)
        %Etve condition to convert ploar into rectangular components
        e_TVE=norm((vcpx-vi),2)/norm(vi,2);%etve condition
        a(i,4)=e_TVE;
        if e_TVE<=0.001 
           continue;
        else
            s=p;
            a(s,6)=vp; %vs
            a(s,5)=tp;%ts
            a(s,7)=alphap;%alps
            % a(s,8)=a(p,6)*(cos(a(p,7))+1i*sin(a(p,7))); %Phasors of Storage point
            break;
        end  
    end 
end
a(n,6)=vn; %vs,reserve the last data
a(n,5)=tn;%ts
a(n,7)=alphan;%alps
x=1;
for y=1:1:20001
    if a(y,5)>0 || a(y,6)>0 || a(y,6)>0
       b(x,1)=a(y,5);
       b(x,2)=a(y,6);
       b(x,3)=a(y,7);
       x=x+1; 
    end   
end
```

Figure 1 is the original (Uncompressed data):

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2 is the compressed data result:

[image: Figure 2]

Figure 3 is the desired result:

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Okay let me show you my coding and desired result

Comment: Bro please check again I have added code and the desired output image.

Comment: I also want to send you Data file that contains 20,000 data point which I have compressed .... can you tell me how can I send you that file? file extension is .mat